# Python script to monitor process and sub-processes

Tags: python, linux, algorithm, subprocess, psutil

I have a Python script which monitors a process and its sub-processes for CPU and memory utilization by the process.

The script continuously checks whether the process or one of its sub-processes is `Active`. Once the process and all its sub-processes are in an `Inactive` state, the Python script exits.

So, the problem I am facing here for a specific process is -

1. Process starts
2. Process creates sub-process-1
3. Process creates sub-process-2
4. Process creates sub-process-3 (`Active` at latest moment)
5. Terminate sub-process-3 ***(At this point the process and all of its sub-processes are `Inactive`)***
6. Process creates sub-process-4 (`Active` at latest moment)

So, if my script checks whether the process or one of the sub-processes is `Active` at [5] it returns false and terminates!

In short: There is a short time span where the process and all its sub-processes are in an `Inactive` state (i.e. the time between a sub-process killed and a new sub-process is yet to be spawned). If my script checks for the status at this point of time, it returns false, because everything is inactive.

Could anyone please provide me with any solution or address this problem?

```
while(bIsProcessActive == True):
    bIsProcessActive = False
    if (proc.is_running() and proc.status != psutil.STATUS_ZOMBIE):
        bIsProcessActive = True
        cpu_usage = proc.get_cpu_percent(interval = 2)
        memory_usage = proc.get_memory_info().rss
    for child in proc.get_children():
        if child.is_running() and child.status != psutil.STATUS_ZOMBIE:
            // Add to memory and CPU usage of parent process
            if bIsProcessActive == False and childutilization[0] == True:
                bIsProcessActive = True
```

Comment: Look at how [`supervisord`](http://supervisord.org/), systemd, upstart, [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/) are implemented

Answer (score 3):

Since your process can have children surviving the parent's death you can't effectively monitor the children based solely on the parent information since the parent ID for the child becomes 1 when the parent exits - if you didn't manage to get the child ID before the parent death you can't locate it anymore.

One way to address this is to use the **process group ID** (pgid) instead: the process and all its descendents will have the same pgid. 
Only works if the descendents don't transform themselves in process group leaders, so assuming this to be true going forward.

With this in mind you can always scan the running processes and locate the children even if the parent is no longer running.

It may help if the monitoring script itself becomes a process group leader - restricts the pgid to only its descendants.

Look at:

- os.setpgrp()
- os.getpgrp()
- ps -eo pid,ppid,pgid

I used this technique in a monitoring script for a sw build analysis tool called BuildIn, you can peek at it here: https://buildin.apartsw.com/wrap.html. Sorry for the advertisement

Comment: Thank you Dan! Your inputs will surely help me to make the script more robust.

Comment: But current issue I am facing is -
There is a short time span where process and all it's sub-processes are in inactive state.(i.e. time between a sub-process killed and a new sub-process is yet to be spawned). If my script checks for active status at this point of time it returns false.

Comment: The implementation is incorrect somewhere since based on your description the parent is still running at this moment (otherwise it couldn't start a new child process later) - it should thus return true. Or the description doesn't reflect what's actually happenning.

Comment: I tend to think that what's happening is that there are child processes spawned after the `proc.get_children()` call in the `last` iteration in which the parent is still alive - which are exactly the ones you can't locate anymore that I mentioned in my answer.