# I need to trace all child processes created by given process in Linux (or POSIX system)

Tags: linux, unix, posix

I have process that creates many child processes. And each child process may create subsequent child processes.
How do I get list of all created processes with their command-line arguments?
And I, preferably, need to know parent process of each child process.

So I need for each process to get pid, ppid and commandline. And then I can analyze that data.

In Windows I can gather this data with tool like ProcessMonitor (which hooks system calls like CreateProcess).
I suppose there exists a similar mechanism in Linux?

**EDIT:**
So there are two ways in Linux:

- Use `exec strace -s 9999 -f -e trace=execve -p [pid of process] >& strace.log`. Then parse it with some simple *perl* script it and generate a tree of child processes. I ended up using it. Drawback is that *strace* debugs all process tree. Some programs fail because of that.
- Use `auditctl`. It directly logs specific system calls, without debugging. Similar to *Process Monitor* tool from Windows. I didn't try it. Possibly the log may be parsed to generate tree of child processes, similar to *strace*. Though, it will be more difficult to parse, as the log will need to be filtered to contain only information from the process tree of our interest.

Comment: [I wrote a post comparing the different options here](https://natanyellin.com/posts/tracking-running-processes-on-linux/)

Comment: strace forks that `execve` gets some info, but e.g.
```
5:execve("/usr/libexec/baloo_file_extractor", ["/usr/libexec/baloo_file_extracto"...],
```
You can see it omits most of the arguments!

Also, not all child processes (threads?) are `execve`; in my case the daemon created some with `clone()` but never `execve()`. I think those don't have command lines.

It would be awesome if `strace `--follow-forks` or a better tracing tool had an option to print "Thread 45306 clone()d by parent 45304" or "Process 45887 execve() by parent 45306 with command line "...."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean get that info at a certain moment of time it's not *that* simple, you may want to check my answers to these questions for additional things to consider:

- [Linux: the most reliable way to terminate a family of processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30980234/linux-the-most-reliable-way-to-terminate-a-family-of-processes/31004557?noredirect=1#comment50067451_31004557)
- [Python script to monitor process and sub-processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30780487/python-script-to-monitor-process-and-sub-processes/30783125#30783125)

IMHO the easiest way to obtain various process information at a certain moment is from files under the `/proc/<pid>` directory, see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html

If you want the (historical) info for the entire lifespan of a process `strace` may capture some of it (but it can be performance impacting, donno if that works for you): https://superuser.com/questions/79869/will-strace-watch-system-calls-recursively-on-child-processes-of-the-main-proces

Comment: I need the data for the entire lifespan of a process tree. I looked the strace(1) man page, it seems that this tool may accomplish my task. Can strace(1) be configured to trace the execve(2) syscall of all child processes recursively and log the data to some file? For each traced call I need the pid, ppid and call arguments (the command line). Other system calls are better to be ignored, because otherwise there will be huge performance hit...

Comment: I believe `strace -f -e execve <program cmdline> >& path/logfile` would be close to what you're looking for. Won't give you ppid directly, you'd need to *compute* that.